# powershell workflow and parallel not giving output

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following script and it creates the out file correctly, but it's empty. I'm not sure what it's missing exactly. This is my first attempt with using workflows.

```
workflow DisableIISParallel
{
    $ScriptPath = "C:\Scripts\Server_Lists"
    $OLD = "Legacy-Servers"
    $OldList = Get-Content "$ScriptPath\$OLD.txt"
    $objHost=$Records.Length

    function DisableIIS ($appName) {
        $objHostStr = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry([string]$objHost).HostName
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $objHostStr { iisreset /stop }
        Set-Service -Name W3SVC -StartupType Disabled -Status Stopped -ComputerName $objHostStr
        Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -ComputerName $objHostStr | 
            where { $_.name -eq "W3SVC" } | 
            Format-Table -Property @{Expression={$_.PSComputerName};Label="Server";width=18}, 
                                   @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Service";width=45}, 
                                   @{Expression={$_.StartMode};Label="Mode";width=10}, 
                                   @{Expression={$_.State};Label="State";width=10}, 
                                   @{Expression={$_.Status};Label="Status";width=10} | 
            Format-List | out-string -s | ? {$_} | Out-File C:\Scripts\Output\$appName.log -Append
        Write-Output "" | Out-File C:\Scripts\Output\$appName.log -Append
    }
    foreach -parallel($objHost in $OldList)
    {
        $appName = $OLD
        DisableIIS $appName
    }
}

DisableIISParallel
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit is not right:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -ComputerName $objHostStr | 
            where { $_.name -eq "W3SVC" } | 
            Format-Table -Property @{Expression={$_.PSComputerName};Label="Server";width=18}, 
                                   @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Service";width=45}, 
                                   @{Expression={$_.StartMode};Label="Mode";width=10}, 
                                   @{Expression={$_.State};Label="State";width=10}, 
                                   @{Expression={$_.Status};Label="Status";width=10} | 
            Format-List | out-string -s | ? {$_} | Out-File C:\Scripts\Output\$appName.log -Append
```

You should not run the output of one format command (Format-Table) into another format command (Format-List).

Try this (assuming you want tabular format - if not, change the Format-Table to Format-List):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -ComputerName $objHostStr | 
            where { $_.name -eq "W3SVC" } | 
            Format-Table @{Expression={$_.PSComputerName};Label="Server";width=18}, 
                         @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Service";width=45}, 
                         @{Expression={$_.StartMode};Label="Mode";width=10}, 
                         @{Expression={$_.State};Label="State";width=10}, 
                         @{Expression={$_.Status};Label="Status";width=10} >> C:\Scripts\Output\$appName.log
```

And pass in all the variables required to the function e.g.:

```
function DisableIIS ($appName, $objHost) {
    ...
}
foreach -parallel($objHost in $OldList)
{
    $appName = $OLD
    DisableIIS $appName $objHost
}
```

Comment: So the file is being created but there is still no output in it? Also see the updated answer.